Using Bicep to configure SQL vulnerability assessment baselines on a new SQL server
I'm trying to setup a vulnerability assessment, with Express configuration, for a SQL server in Azure using Bicep. The following is a snippet of how I have my Bicep.
resource server 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2023-08-01-preview' = {
  name: 'sql'

  resource sqlVulnerabilityAssessment 'sqlVulnerabilityAssessments@2023-08-01-preview' = {
    name: 'serverVulnerabilityAssessment'
    properties: {
      state: 'Enabled'
    }
  }

  resource database 'databases' = {
    name: 'dbName'

    resource vulnerabilityAssessment 'sqlVulnerabilityAssessments@2023-08-01-preview' existing = {
      name: 'databaseVulnerabilityAssessment'

      resource baselines 'baselines@2023-08-01-preview' = {
        name: 'baseline'

        properties: {
          latestScan: false
          results: {
            // ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This works fine for any database that already has performed a vulnerability scan. The problem is that this does not work on newly created SQL server. I get the following error when I deploy a new SQL server:
{
    "code": "SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentScanResultsAreNotAvailableYet",
    "message": "SQL vulnerability assessment results are not available yet, please try again later."
}

The SQL server will be created, but the baseline will not be applied. I can fix this by manually doing a vulnerability scan. When these results are available a deploy will work again.
From the Bicep documentation I can only see that the Scan resources for both server and database are readonly.
How do I properly deploy this for a new server so that I immediately have my baseline configured instead of deploying multiple times when a first scan result is available?
